# Auto-Launch app from the dmg

Tags: macos, dmg

Is there a way, as soon as a .dmg is mounted, without any user-action the contained .app launches, just like windows has autorun.ini?

Comment: Running apps from a DMG is bad practice, I would suggest. It doesn't offer any advantages, and at best means that the app 'disappears' if the dmg is unmounted, e.g. after reboot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.

This in its most general application would be an egregious security risk.  There is a [provision to display a license prompt at mount time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103468/5472), however.

btw, Windows auto-run [as opposed to auto-play] has been disabled for many years [since Windows 7] for similar reasons.